# i am trying add css to all ' li ' element after scroll down but it apply only first li

Tags: javascript, css, html

After scrolling down, it's applying only the home button.

Here is my code.

```
<ul class="mainmenu nav sf-menu" style="float: right;">
  <li class="active" id="scrl-li">
    <a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
   </li>
   <li  id="scrl-li">
     <a href="about.html" ><span>About Us</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="scrl-li">  
     <a href="about.html" ><span>Services</span></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.counter').html(scrollTop);

        if (scrollTop >= 100) {
            $("#scrl-li").css("marginTop","-20px");
        } else if (scrollTop < 100) {
            $("#scrl-li").css("marginTop","0px");
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: you repeated the same id twice: use class instead both in the markup and in the script

Comment: Ids are singular.

Comment: yeah man .. its working you saved my day .. thank you so much

Comment: A better solution would be to just toggle a class on the UL and adjust the styles with CSS.  `ul.sf-menu li { margin-top: 0px;}  ul.sf-menu.scrolled li { margin-top: 20px;}`  and `$("ul.sf-menu").toggleClass(scrollTop >= 100)`

Answer (score 0):

The other posters are correct that you should only have one of an ID per page, but you may still be able to work around the problem if you do not have control of the markup by using
$("[id='scrl-li']") to target the elements instead of $("#scrl-li").

Answer (score 0):

Id's should be unique and not repeated across elements. Changing your id's to classes makes this code work:

Change the jquery id references as well as the html id references to classes

```
<li id="scrl-li">
```

to...

```
<li class="scrl-li">
```

and....

```
$("#scrl-li")
```

to...

```
$(".scrl-li")
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/794901/

View the html code as you scroll and you will see the margin attributes appear and change accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have more ids in your html template. You can have only one id="scrl-li".

In you html template replace the id with class and in the jquery instead of calling $("#scrl-li"), you will have to use $(".scrl-li").

Hope this will help you.